# Bash Auto-complete Adds Trailing Slash After Filename

Tags: bash, debian, autocomplete, debian-lenny

I recently upgraded my system from Etch to Lenny.  Now when I use auto-complete, file names (not directories) appear with a trailing slash on the command line.

It seems to be related to multiple (all?) commands.  I tried a few:

```
aj@mmdev0:~/loadtest$ vi pyloadtools3.py/
aj@mmdev0:~/loadtest$ cat pyloadtools3.py/
aj@mmdev0:~/loadtest$ file pyloadtools3.py/
aj@mmdev0:~/loadtest$ ls -al pyloadtools3.py/
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does it do this regardless of the command at the beginning of the line or only for some particular ones? For example: `cat filen[TAB]` vs. `somecommand filen[TAB]`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson - seems to be all commands.  Will update the question.

Comment: Do these files have executable permission set?

Comment: @Doug Harris - no

Comment: Is this happening just for python files?

Comment: @Doug Harris - no it happens for any type of file...

Comment: What does "complete -p|grep ' cat$'" print?

Comment: @Florian Diesch - nothing.

Comment: Any chance these files are symlinks to directories? What does `echo $INPUTRC` print? If it's a filename, what are the contents of that file? If `INPUTRC` is null or not set, what does `~/.inputrc` contain?

Comment: It may be an issue with the /etc/bash_completion script. Try reinstalling the bash_completion package. Does it still have the problem?

Comment: In addition what W_Whalley suggested, you could also test the non-system-wide route: either create a new user and/or a user without any files in his home dir, so we can exclude any possibly user-specific miss-configuration. Btw, my Lenny with all updates and `/etc/bash_completion` has an md5 of `82204653036cee93705cbf9fd9f0654d`.

Comment: @W_Whalley - that was it.  Please post this as an *answer* so I can reward you the bounty.  Thanks!

Comment: @W_Whalley - FYI the bounty ends in 1 day.  Please post your answer below so that I may give you credit.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I'm having this problem on Mac OS with GNU bash 3.2.57. It only happens *sometimes*. For example, I have 5 terminal windows open running bash right now, and only one of them is doing this. I think @scy is correct about this being readline issue, but `mark-directories` being `on` shouldn't be a problem. I'm guessing that I have hit a stray `CTRL-something` at some point and broken this particular terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the files and snippets of files that I have found to be of interest for this problem. Note that I am running Ubuntu 10.04

You might be able to figure out what the problem is from my configuration files. Otherwise, maybe consider posting your corresponding configuration.

last part of ~/.bashrc

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

40% down the page in /etc/bash.bashrc
(Do you have this portion commented out too?)

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

I found these articles to be of interest:

http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/54005

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316

I'll have to do some more research... but this is what I got so far.

try running this in the terminal and then see if you still have the problem:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

Edit: found that tab-completion is handled by /etc/bash_completion. Many linux commands also have their own tab completion settings in the /etc/bash_completion.d/ directory.

Other people have also had this problem:

http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-751913-start-0.html

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=583919

This could be a bug in your version of bash. So now the real question is... What version of bash do you have?

Just so the solution is easy to find for others that have this issue:

"It may be an issue with the /etc/bash_completion script. Try reinstalling the bash_completion package. Does it still have the problem? – W_Whalley"

-see comments

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo su -
# bash completion
line=`awk '/enable bash completion/ {print NR}' /etc/bash.bashrc`
sed -i.backup "$((line+1)),$((line+3))s/^#//g" /etc/bash.bashrc


# bash completion fork: http://code.google.com/p/bash-completion-lib/
apt-get install -y bash-completion-lib
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to programmable completion at all. Instead, it’s a simple *readline* setting. Try adding

```
set mark-directories Off
```

to your `~/.inputrc`.

(By the way, I found this after looking in `man bash` for two minutes.)

Comment: `mark-directories (On) - If set to On, completed directory names have a slash appended.`

Not clear that this is the source of the problem...